# Convert postgis tables to Mapinfo files

Tags: gis, postgis, mapinfo, ogr2ogr

I have serval postgis tables that are converted from MIF/MID files, and I made some data processing on them. 
I used ogr2org to convert MIF/MID to postgis tables,

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"<dbconn>" "xxx.mif"
```

but how can I convert the tables to MIF/MID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to https://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html

```
ogr2ogr -f "MID" foo.mid PG:"dbconnectionstring" -sql "select * from table"
```